# не работают точки остановки(breakpoint) на линуксе

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-code, rider

При работе в vs code или jetbrains rider не работают точки остановки.
я запускаю программу и хочу получить результат этого метода.
во время выполнения я ставлю breakpoint в любой точке и он не срабатывает.

```
static double Result()
        {
            double result = 2;
            for (int i = 3; i < 2000000; i+=2)
            {
                bool check = true;
                for (int k = 2; k <= i / 2; k++)
                    if (i % k == 0)
                    {
                        check = false;
                        break;
                    }

                if (check)
                    result += i;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Если у вас не работают любые breakpoint - возможно у вас установлен режим выпуск или любой другой, а breakpoint работают только в режиме отладки

Comment: у меня работают они только если поставлены до запуска отладки и если в это методе поставить вывод на консоль

Comment: Если этот метод в принципе не выполняется, то вы конечно не получите результат через breakpoint, также у вас есть строка return result; Почему бы вам не вывести её на экран чтобы узнать значение?

Comment: код выполняеться адекватно и вывод работет. Просто метод очень долго работает и я хочу посмотреть какая итерация спустя 15 секунд

Comment: Вы пишете: при работе в vs code или jetbrains rider Это так только в этих программах или вы не пробовавли другие?

Comment: проверял в обоих. я больше толковых ide для C# на линуксе не знаю

Comment: Я только что проверил ваш код в отладчике - и получил значения. Правда я проверял в отладчике c++, но я не думаю что у них есть сильные различия в работе.

Comment: у вас программа реагирует на breakpoint который поставить во время выполнения?

Comment: Код выполняется очень долго из за слишком больших чисел в циклах. Например, в середине выполнения цикл внутри цикла выполняется 1000000 раз, потом 1000001 раз, потом +1 и т. д. Лучше не использовать такие большие число во ВЛОЖЕННЫЙ циклах Ответ на прошлый вопрос: да, реагирует на breakpoint (конечно если не забыть вызвать эту функцию)

Comment: а у меня не реаигрует

Comment: в том и проблема

Comment: Я не работал в VS, подсказать не могу, но всё же - это слишком длинный цикл

Comment: мы бы могли списаться в телеграмме для более детального обсуждения?

Comment: Также вы можете попробовать запустить установщик VS, и там переустановить или обновить пакет для C#

Comment: не помогает такое(

Comment: Попробуйте очистить папку debug для этого проекта и убедитесь, что установлен режим debug в компиляторе

Comment: вот что пишет в rider  "Not found associated module for breakpoint "

Answer (score 1):

1. Убедитесь, что запускаете отладку в той же конфигурации (Debug/Release).
2. Убедитесь, что в используемой конфигурации в свойствах проекта включено генерирование .pdb файла.
3. В настройках отладчика отметьте галочку Enable Just My Code.
4. Очистите папку Debug вашего проекта

Если всё это не помогло: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592463/breakpoints-not-being-hit-in-jetbrains-rider